# how to make a programme modify itself on running in c

Tags: c, self-modifying

i have a simple programme that shuts down a computer but it always gets detected as a virus when i share the exe file so i was wondering if i could make the programme treat a part of the code like a comment until it is run.
for example before it is run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    if(programme is running)
    {remove /* on line 8;}
    /*system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s");*/
    return 0;
}
```

i tried storing it in a zip but it still gets detected as a virus. that is why i was looking for a way to make it self modifying so it can bypass windows security

Comment: What is your motivation for this?  Are you trying to create a virus that sneaks by the standard virus checks?

Comment: @TomKarzes nah i just wanted to prank my bro by making him open it

Comment: You would have to add the new source code to your program (as text) and a compiler which takes the new program and compiles it, saving over itself. Anti-virus software can detect behavior like that though AFAIK.

Comment: I don't know if this would actually work but you could try to store the system command string in a file and load it while running the program or you might be able to save an encrypted version of the command in the program itself and decrypt it at runtime.

Comment: Well, you're trying to do something malicious, and the software meant for catching attempts to do malicious things is catching you trying to do something malicious. It appears everything here is working as intended.

Comment: I'm conflicted about whether or not this question should be closed. "How to modify code at runtime" is a perfectly reasonable question on its own, "How to trick some unspecified anti-virus software" is not on-topic here though.

Comment: "but it always gets detected as a virus when i share the exe file" That's because of mail client restrictions, it has nothing to do with your program or what your program does. Neither mail clients nor anti-virus are anywhere near as smarts as to analyze your exe and search for a specific Windows API calls, let alone analyze the parameter string passed to `system`.

Comment: @Cubic Potentially harmful software has been debated extensively on meta in the past. The SO policy is that these questions are on-topic; we don't know or can be held responsible for the reason why someone is writing a certain program. There is also no difference between the knowledge of how to create malware and the knowledge of how to protect against malware - that's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking cannot be done. During compilation, all comments are disregarded, so the compiled binary code will have no trace of the comments.

Within the specifications of the C language, it is not possible to change the executable code, only modifiable data.

Hence, unless you will be doing [low-level tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447013/how-to-write-self-modifying-code-in-c) (possibly outdated) you are limited to modifying the program data.

You could, for example, store the system command string `"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s"` in an "encrypted" string:

```
  char command[] = "D;]XJOEPXT]Tztufn43]tivuepxo!0t";
```

and then have the code modify it into the real command before running it. In this case:

```
   for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(command)-1; i++) command[i] = command[i] - 1;
   system(command);
```

However, as others have commented, this is unlikely to make a difference in your underlying problem of the program being treated as a threat.

I would guess that making a truly self-modifying program makes it more - and not less - likely that the OS or anti-malware monitoring will see the program as a threat.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd classify creating executable code at runtime a "trick". It's certainly not standardised in C (because the specifics are necessarily different between platforms), but it mostly amounts to using OS functions in exactly the way they were intended to be used, no trickery required.

Comment: Furthermore on very low level code in embedded systems and bootloaders, you sometimes need to execute things from RAM when code would normally get executed from flash. One way to do this is to provide a `uint8_t` array of raw op codes in pure binary, corresponding to a function written with the proper calling convention. Than call this array from inline asm as if it was a function. So it is certainly possible, I've done it many times, but it is quite intricate and "hacky" even in an embedded system.