# Writing a Self modifying code at runtime in C/C++

Tags: c++, x86, reverse-engineering, self-modifying

i have some questions,

is possible to make a programm in windows that modify itself?

i write this program that use the _asm{} function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print() //FUNCTION TO MODIFY
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}

void Crypt(int adr)
{
    _asm {

        mov eax, adr

        xor_loop:
        xor byte ptr [eax], 0x24 
            inc eax
            cmp eax, 0xC3 //compare ret opcode
            jne xor_loop
    }

}

int main()
{
    print();

    void *ptr = print;  //address example : 003812E4

    cout << "Address : " << ptr << "\n";

    int mem;

    _asm {
        lea eax, print
        mov mem, eax
        call eax
    }

    cout << "EAX : " << mem << "\n";

    Crypt(mem);
    
    return 0;
}
```

but dosent work properly i dont why, any help?

pseudocode:

```
print function:
   mov eax, 0x80
   add eax, 0x02
   call eax
   ret

modify:
   lea eax, print
   xor byte ptr [eax], 0x24 //xor for modify opcode
   inc eax       //increase eax 1 byte
   cmp eax, 0xC3 //compare ret opcode
   jne modify

---------------------------------------------
modify print function example:
   mul eax
   mov eax, edx
   jnz ebx
   ret
```

Comment: Modifying program code is often used by malware, so modern operating systems, runtime libraries, and compilers usually prevent that. There are low end embedded systems that allow that, either because the environment is controlled enough that it's not an issue, or the system just doesn't have the resources to add that safety. Or very old systems before malware prevention was put in place.

Comment: It will not be easy to do so. The OS has all kinds of low-level build in stuff to prevent modifying code. Code pages are read-only and Data pages are flagged to not be executable.

Comment: [How to write self modifying code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447013/how-to-write-self-modifying-code-in-c)

Comment: I even doubt sefl modifying code is needed. You can generate an encrypted string at compile time, and just decrypt it to a temporary buffer whenever you need it at runtime. E.g. like this : https://godbolt.org/z/cd6d99cnq (note that the data segment contains an obfuscated string). And yes the key should probably be somewhere else in memory (just a short demo)

Comment: Why do you feel you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should save your code in the `.data` section that you can't change the code in the `.code` section as it is protected(readonly).

There is an idea:

1. allocate a block of memory in the heap section to save function you want to change
2. copy the function code bytes into that memory
3. change the code and call the new function with the address you allocated.

Comment: Note that with many systems (Windows for sure, not certain of *nix flavors) you will need to use a function in order that heap-allocated memory be executable. On Windows the needed function is VirtualProtect.

Comment: Nice idea however the `.data` segement will not have its execute flag set on its pages. And the `.code` page will be readonly. So you can't run code from either location. (Which is a good thing)