# Why is this shellcode causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, shellcode

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char code[] = "\x31\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\xf7\xdb\x53\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";

int main()
{
    printf("len:%d bytes\n", strlen(code));
    (*(void(*)()) code)();
    return 0;
}
```

Using the gcc compiler, I first simply compiled using

```
 gcc program.c -o program
```

When I ran that I got a Segmentation Fault. Next, I tried to compile using

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o test test.c
```

That worked and I got the shell. What I am wondering is why I need to pass those commands while compiling for it to work. My goal is to make it work without having to pass those commands. How can I achieve that goal?

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `const char code[]`?

Comment: ahh @tangrs that did the trick

Comment: Related: [segmentation fault with .text .data and main (main in .data section)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34350582) / [Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58260465)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writeable data in static storage (such as your `code` array) usually ends up in the `.data` section which is usually marked “not executable.” Mark the array as `const` so it ends up in `.rodata` resp. `.text` and can be executed.