# Find the length of a null terminated string (Assembly language)

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

I am trying to write a procedure to find the length of a null-terminated string and store the length in `eax`. The start address of the string is stored in `edx` before calling the procedure.

Here's my code, I don't know what's wrong:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
myString BYTE "Hello programmers", 0


strLength PROC
mov eax , 0
mov ebx , '/0'
mov esi , 0
Condition:
movzx ecx , myString[esi]
cmp ebx , ecx
je ExitLoop
inc esi
inc eax
jmp Condition
ExitLoop:
ret
StrLength ENDP



main PROC
lea edx, myString
call strLength 

INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

[image: error]

Line 14 is : Condition
Line 21 is : ExitLoop:
Line 17 is : je ExitLoop
Line 20 is : jmp Condition
Line 29 is : call strLength
Line 38 is : INVOKE ExitProcess,0
and line 70 doesn't exist

Comment: Please show us the error message. What I can see is a typo in `call strLength` which should be `call StrLength`.

Comment: You're code should work fine, but you don't need to maintain two counters, and you can `cmp` with an immediate `0`, or `test ecx, ecx`.

Comment: `'/0'` looks wrong. Did you mean to use `'\0'`'? (which of course can be replaced with just `0`).

Comment: @xiver77 can you check it now please

Comment: Don't put code in the data section. You need a `.code` directive.

Comment: @Michael even when I use 0 I still get the same list of errors

Comment: @Michael now it's working thank you so much

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of [segmentation fault with .text .data and main (main in .data section)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34350582) in that the problem is the same, but the symptoms are very different with MASM refusing to assemble it, vs. other assemblers just assembling the same way regardless of section.

Comment: Also, this is of course quite inefficient.  You are doing one good thing, though, loading with `movzx` instead of `mov cl , myString[esi]`.  But wait a minute, you're hard-coding the symbol name into the loop?  Why do you have 2 counters that both start at zero?  It would have made some sense to have one pointer increment and one counter increment, but when the index and counter are always the same, that's just obvious duplication of work.

Comment: Byte-at-a-time is much slower than strlen has to be ([Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676035)), but if you are going to do that, [Return a pointer at a specific position - Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199332) shows a good `strchr` loop that does a pointer-increment inside the loop.  Replace the `cmp cl, sil` with `cmp cl, 0` or `test ecx, ecx` and it's a strlen instead of strchr.  (And subtract the pointer at the end, to return a length instead of a pointer to the terminating 0.)