# Can i execute code that resides in data segment (ELF binary)?

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, elf, shellcode

In the way to understanding binaries (Virtual memory layout, execution...etc), I've written a `C` code that declares a global string which contains bytes of an executable code, then i overwrote the return address from the `main()` function to that executable code using a simple trick by declaring a pointer (`PTR`) in `main()` which is a local area of memory reserved on the stack 2 WORDS far away from the return address from the `main()`, so all i do is assigning the address of the return address to that pointer `(PTR=(int*)&PTR+2)` and then overwrite the content of that address with the address of the executable code (the static string).
 Now the dilemma is that, whenever i compile and i execute, i receive a **segmentation fault**.
The executable code does no memory `input/output` (its just a bunch of `NOPs`). 
Using GDB i made sure that the process works perfectly: the return address is changed to be the string's address but the return never happens.
All i know is that the executable code is mapped to pages in virtual memory thar are marked `RW` (`.data` & `.bss` segments) so maybe there's no way to do such a code execution unless code is injected in an `executable` area of memory (Pages that are marked `RE`). That's my theory about the subject, i invite you to give more details.

```
char code[]="\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90"; //a static string contains executable code

int main()
{
int *return_address; //Pointer to the return address - uninitialized
return_address = (int *)&return_address + 2; //Initializing the return address - according to stack layout
(*return_address) = (int)code; //Overwriting the return address with the code's address
}
```

Comment: You may want to call mprotect sycall with PROT_EXEC flag added... There is no x permission on data page on many architectures (x86 too), check the memory maps in linux by reading /proc/$PID/maps file while the application is running (stopped in gdb), where $PID is the pid of target process. You will see data/bss segment loaded with rw- permission.

Comment: @osgx It is exactly the same thing i guessed, does older linux kernels (like before 2007) allow this kind of execution ?

Comment: did you? You may check maps file on older kernel. There is wiki page on technology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection and "NX bit" / "XD bit" technology may be needed in CPU and kernel to ... add 'Executable' bit to page-level translations of hardware (OS may have 3bit rwx permissions; but hardware had no x bit). PAE should be turned on in 32-bit x86 mode too. (detailed information is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)

Comment: afr0ck, and what is your real question? Do you want any more detailed links?

Comment: Linux kernels > 2.3 supports full PAE with XD bit so i really need a very old Linux kernel to make such an attempt. Btw thanks for helping. @osgx

Comment: The question was : can i execute the program above without having an segmentation fault ?...and it turned out to be impossible due to memory protection !

Comment: afr0ck, there are tools to change linux settings for one application, for example `execstack` tool (http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack; the stack may be switched to rwx; check 2004 article). kernels >2.3 may support PAE, but at the same time, PAE may be not enabled in kernel configuration (at build time; there was linux-generic-pae variant of kernel).

Comment: linker may change flags on sections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863200/why-data-and-stack-segments-are-executable

Comment: That was literally helpful, Thanks @osgx.

Comment: If you want to close the question as solved, you may (or may not) click "v"-shaped button left to the correct answer (accept it). Or you may want to wait for someone with better answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i receive a segmentation fault.

It is hardware control of data execution prevention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection#Linux) - you can't just jump to data page if it has no 'x' (execute) bit set in page tables. Memory mappings with all bits are listed in `/proc/$pid/maps` / `/proc/$pid/smaps` files as 'rwx' for writable code, 'rw-' for data without execution, 'r--' for readonly data, 'r-x' for normal code.

If you want to execute data, you should call `mprotect` syscall with `PROT_EXEC` flag on the section of your data which wants to be code.

In x86 world this was fully implemented as ["NX bit" / "XD bit" feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) in Pentium 4 (Prescott) and newer (Core, Core2, Core i*, core m) / in  Athlon 64 / Opteron and newer. If OS works in 32-bit mode, it must turn on PAE to have this bit in page table. In x86_64 mode (64-bit) there is always NX/XD bit supported.

First variants of support were added to linux around 2004: http://linuxgazette.net/107/pramode.html

In 2007 you may have outdated hardware, old kernel or 32-bit mode kernel without PAE.

Info about NX/XD bits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit

Sometimes 'rwx' mode may be prohibited, check [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W^X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX).

For pre-NX systems there were solutions based on segment registers of x86 to partially disable part of memory space from executing.

> can i execute the program above without having an segmentation fault ?

You can:

- make the data page executable by calling `mprotect` on it with `PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC`
- make the data segment of elf file marked as executable (need to hack deeply inside `ld` scripts - default is in `ld --verbose`)
- **make all pages including `.data` and the heap executable (not just the stack)

  with ld or gcc `-z execstack`**
- move shellcode to text data of elf file
- try to disable nx/xd bit in kernel (hard; recompilation may be needed)
- use 32-bit OS (kernel) without PAE option enabled (build time option).
- use older cpu without NX/XD

Comment: PS: someone may (but should not, according to law) use *spray* to get own code written in remote process in executable pages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT_spraying). Will not work on RISC and gogole NaCL (they have no variable length instruction encoding or jump to the middle of instruction) and on modern JIT with anti-spray.

Comment: ubuntus page of nx/xd: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#nx "The 64bit and 32bit -server and -generic-pae kernels are compiled with PAE addressing. Starting in Ubuntu 9.10, this protection is partially emulated for processors lacking NX when running on a 32bit kernel .. Starting in Ubuntu 11.04, BIOS NX settings are ignored by the kernel." And color matrix.

Comment: Turns out that using `mprotect` is quite easy, giving a zone through start address and length. The only attention point is that the start address must be page-aligned (`addr & ~4095`). Note that GDB (at least rr) freaks out when stepping inside mprotect call.