# Code works when run from section .data, but segmentation faults in section .text

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

Why doesn't the following code give a segmentation fault?

```
global _start
section .data 

_start:
    mov ecx, 3
    xor byte[_start+1], 0x02
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 2
    int 80h
```

I expected it to segfault at the same place (line marked with a comment) as when the same code is run in the `.text` section:

```
global _start
section .text  ; changed from data to text

_start:
    mov ecx, 3
    xor byte[_start+1], 0x02   ; ******get segmentation fault here
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 2
    int 80h
```

Now, I know that section `.data` is for read-write, and section `.text` is for read only.
But why would it matter when I try to access illegal memory address?

For the example here, I expected to get segmentation fault also at section `.data`, in the same place that I got it in section `.text`.

Comment: Um, the `xor` instruction is modifying the byte at `_start+1`. In a `text` section, that byte is read-only, whereas in a `data` section, it is writeable. It seems that you already know enough information to answer your own question, so I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 4):

`[_start+1]` is clearly not an illegal address.  It's part of the 5 bytes encoding `mov ecx, 3`.  (look at `objdump -Mintel -drw a.out` to see disassembly with the hex machine code).

IDK why you think there would be a problem writing to an address in `.data` where you've defined the contents.  It's more common to use pseudo-instructions like `db` to assemble bytes into the data section, but assemblers will happily assemble instructions or `db` into bytes anywhere you put them.

---

The crash you'd *expect* from the `.data` version is from `_start` being mapped without execute permission but thanks to surprising defaults in the toolchain, programs with asm source files often end up with read-implies-exec (like `gcc -zexecstack`) unless you take precautions to avoid that:

- [Why data and stack segments are executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7863200)
- [Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58260465)

If you applied that  `section .note.GNU-stack noalloc noexec nowrite progbits` change, code fetch from RIP=`_start` *would* fault.

---

**The version that tries to write to the `.text` section of course segfaults because it's mapped read-only.**

Comment: Ok, so I understand why I don't get seg-fault in section .data. But now I got confused- why do I get segfault at section .text? why is it a problem to access the first byte of [_start+1] in this section?

Comment: @Rodrigo: (revised previous comment): You said in your question that you know `.text` is mapped read-only.  What happens when an instruction tries to write to a page that's mapped read-only?

Comment: Related: a duplicate for non-shellcode questions with arrays in .text accidentally: [x86\_64 Assembly - Segfault when trying to edit a byte within an array in x64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45005078)