# NASM Segmentation fault when modifying a variable that should be in the read-write .data section (section .data doesn't work without a space?)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm having an issue with a program I'm writing in NASM using SASM, I'm using a variable as a counter and once I modified it and try to to save the new value at the used address in memory I get a segmentation fault.
Here are the bits of code concerning the variable:

```
section.data
p_count DW 0

section.text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    mov bx, [p_count]
    inc bx
    mov [p_count], bx

    ret
```

The program stops running when it arrives at the last line here.
Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I modified the code in the post to contain that.

Comment: The line `section.text` is missing a blank between the word "`section`" and the section name. Same for `.data`.

Answer (score 4):

**You forgot the space in `section.data`** (and `.text`), so everything went into the read-only `.text` section by default.

**`section.data` is parsed as a label, like `foo.bar:` would be**, not a `section` directive.  The colon at the end of a label is optional when the label name isn't also a valid instruction mnemonic like `loop:`

The opposite error (valid `section .data` but buggy `section.text`) leads to putting your code into the `.data`, which gets linked into non-executable memory pages.  In that case you'd segfault on code-fetch from the first instruction!

---

You should have gotten a warning from NASM like this:

```
warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]
```

If your NASM didn't warn, use a newer version where it's on by default,
or run NASM with `-Worphan-labels` to enable that useful warning.

Comment: Related: [Code works when run from section .data, but segmentation faults in section .text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38152352) is that opposite error, with code in .data (which happens to work if built in a way that makes .data executable).  Also [x86\_64 Assembly - Segfault when trying to edit a byte within an array in x64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45005078) is a good canonical duplicate for questions without a section directive at all, rather than a failed  attempt to use the .data section.