# G++ & NASM fails to compile code and work in Rocky 9 Linux but compiles fine with Centos 7

Tags: assembly, g++, x86-64, nasm, cpuid

I have g++ code calling assembly code. This compiles in Centos 7 and works in Centos 7 & Rocky 9. However if I compile in Rocky 9 or Centos Stream 9 it fails and segmentation fault on first line of assembly line  "mov r8, rdi". See below

***Compile command***

1. `g++ -c -Wall -g -D_DEBUG -Dx86_64 -pthread -o cpuinfo.o cpuinfo.cpp`
2. `nasm -felf64 -o test1.o test1.asm`
3. `g++ -L../../lib -ltsx64 -pthread -lefence -o cpuinfo cpuinfo.o test1.o`

**g++ code**

```
extern "C" void get_cpuid_info(unsigned long *, const unsigned long func, const unsigned long subfunc);

get_cpuid_info(CPUIDreg.reg, 0, 0);
```

***NASM code**********

```
Global get_cpuid_info 
 
get_cpuid_info:                         
           mov r8, rdi   ;#  array addr
           mov r9, rsi   ;#  leaf
           mov r10, rdx  ;#  subleaf

           push        rax              
           push        rbx              
           push        rcx              
           push        rdx              
           mov         rax, r9         
           mov         rcx, r10
           cpuid                        
           mov         dword [r8], eax
           mov         dword [r8+8], ebx
           mov         dword [r8+16], ecx
           mov         dword [r8+24], edx
           pop         rdx              
           pop         rcx              
           pop         rbx              
           pop         rax              
           ret
```

It compiled successfully in Centos 7 with g++(v4.8.5-44) and NASM(v2.10.07). However when I compiled in a Centos stream 9 or Rocky 9 Linux it throws segmentation fault at the first assembly mov instructions
****get_cpuid_info:
mov r8, rdi ** **

Comment: Is there a `section .data` before your code, or any section directive other than `section .text`?  If so, then probably your code is in a non-executable page.  Does this segfault still happen if you don't link with `-lefence` (That's the "electric fence" malloc checker, right?)  Perhaps the difference between your ancient system (with 9 year old GCC) is [Linux default behavior of executable .data section changed between 5.4 and 5.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64833715) / [Why data and stack segments are executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7863200)

Comment: In any case, you don't need the (unnecessarily overcomplicated) asm for cpuid just use the builtins.

Comment: RAX, RCX, and RDX are call-clobbered; you only need to push/pop RBX.  And CPUID doesn't touch RDI or RSI so you can leave the pointer arg in RDI.  Or like Jester said, throw out the hand-written asm and use GCC's `cpuid.h` for `__cpuid`  [Intrinsics for CPUID like informations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17758409)

Comment: There's no such thing as CentOS 9.

Comment: Peter,
You right about cpuid.h, I am trying to revive some older code with MMX registers, but this simple function fails the same way. I wanted a simple snippet code to make the point in stackoverflow. Thanks for your weblinks, they make for really interesting reading...

Comment: Usually if you have time, it's best to rewrite MMX code to use SSE2 with 128-bit XMM registers, sometimes even if your data naturally only comes in 8-byte chunks so you only have useful data in the low half of a 128-bit XMM.  Or AVX2 with 256-bit YMM registers.  If so, use intrinsics in whatever higher-level language you're using unless you're doing something very tricky that you can't convince a compiler to do equally well.  But yes, getting the MMX code to build and run is of course useful, at least as a "reference" implementation and performance starting point.

Comment: MMX is not *as* efficiently supported as SSE2, for example maybe a throughput of only 1 per cycle for some instructions where the SSE2/AVX2 versions can run on multiple ports.  But MMX instructions are still single-uop and typically 1-cycle latency if they were on older CPUs like Pentium III and Sandybridge.  (https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/)