# How to get c code to execute hex machine code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, shellcode

I want a simple C method to be able to run hex bytecode on a Linux 64 bit machine.  Here's the C program that I have:

```
char code[] = "\x48\x31\xc0";
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int (*func) ();
        func = (int (*)()) code;
        (int)(*func)();
        printf("%s\n","DONE");
}
```

The code that I am trying to run (`"\x48\x31\xc0"`) I obtained by writting this simple assembly program (it's not supposed to really do anything)

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
        xorq %rax, %rax
```

and then compiling and objdump-ing it to obtain the bytecode.

However, when I run my C program I get a segmentation fault.  Any ideas?

Comment: Even if your data segment is executable or you don't have NX enabled, what do you expect this to do? It executes one instruction and then the instruction afterwards (which you don't control) and then the instruction after that, until it reaches memory which doesn't represent legitimate code or code that triggers a segfault.

Comment: You will need to add byte code for a `ret` because the indirect function call you do should be a `call` which pushes the return address onto the stack. Atleast, this is my best educated guess, I have never seen anything like this.

Comment: I expect this to do nothing, but I want it to be able to run without crashing.

Comment: Do you mind about the \0 at the end of the string ?

Comment: char code[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\xc3\0";

Comment: don't use `xorq %rax, %rax`. Use [`xor eax, eax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/995714) instead

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Machine code has to be in an executable page. Your `char code[]` is in the read+write data section, without exec permission, so the code cannot be executed from there.

Here is a simple example of allocating an executable page with `mmap`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main ()
{
  char code[] = {
    0x8D, 0x04, 0x37,           //  lea eax,[rdi+rsi]
    0xC3                        //  ret
  };

  int (*sum) (int, int) = NULL;

  // allocate executable buffer                                             
  sum = mmap (0, sizeof(code), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
              MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  // copy code to buffer
  memcpy (sum, code, sizeof(code));
  // doesn't actually flush cache on x86, but ensure memcpy isn't
  // optimized away as a dead store.
  __builtin___clear_cache (sum, sum + sizeof(sum));  // GNU C

  // run code
  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;
  int c = sum (a, b);

  printf ("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);
}
```

See [another answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960721/how-to-get-c-code-to-execute-hex-bytecode/55893781#55893781) for details about `__builtin___clear_cache`.

Comment: Yes, the `ret` is important to return back into the calling function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just want to add that objdump -d <filename> can get you the byte code for an executable.

Comment: `static const char code[]` is normally linked into the text segment of your executable, which is already mapped read-only + executable.  You don't actually need to copy it.  (Making it non-`const` would be a problem, though; the data segment isn't always executable.)  The important part of this answer vs. the question is the `ret`.  See also [Why does const int main = 195 result in a working program but without the const it ends in a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33305574).  (195 = 0xC3 = `ret`).

Comment: This technique is independent of where the machine code comes from. I included a fragment known at compile time for simplicity, but the concept works with machine code generated at runtime, which is the main use case. You are quick to comment but I think you missed the point.

Comment: I removed the 'static const' in order not to give the impression that the code has to be known at compile time.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you sure it is not in `data` segment, which is read-only and not executable?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: `data` is read/write.  That's where the `.data` section goes, which contains things like `int global_var = 2;`  And yes, I'm sure.  Look at compiler output yourself, and / or use `readelf -a` on binaries produced by gcc + `ld`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant the read-only data segment. Will double check.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Current toolchains don't use a separate *segment* for that. `section .rodata` (or `section .rdata` on Windows) gets linked as part of the text segment, so it's part of the same read+exec mapping as the code.      [What's the difference of section and segment in ELF file format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14361248)

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin and Antoine: update: This answer is still fine, but my `static const code[] = ...` suggestion is no longer sufficient.  Current (2019) GNU Binutils `ld` now links `.rodata` into a separate segment that is read only without exec permission.  It's still easier to use `gcc -z execstack` or `mprotect()` than to mmap+memcpy, though.  I added an answer of my own with full details + working examples.

Comment: @AntoineMathys I thought `__builtin___clear_cache()` isn't required because `sum` is called and so there is a dependency to the result of  `memcpy()`, which depends on the result of `mmap`.  Thought?

Comment: @AntoineMathys: Yes, it's true that GCC doesn't "know" that `mmap` is being used to get anonymous memory, where writing + freeing it has no permanent side effect.  GCC *does* do dead-store elimination if you use `malloc` and compile with `gcc -z execstack`.  In theory it could recognize `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` and behave the same way.  Also, the compiler doesn't "see" the dependency between actually doing the `memcpy` and calling `sum()`, so if you later stored other bytes to the same buffer you'd get only one memcpy, potentially after the first call!

Comment: And yes `__builtin___clear_cache()` expands to zero instructions once we finally get to that stage of code-gen.  As I explained in my edit and comments, and [in my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960721/how-to-get-c-code-to-execute-hex-bytecode/55893781#55893781); it's there to make other code compile correctly by preventing compile-time reordering of things, not to emit any instructions.  It's like a compile-time-only barrier for that region of code.  Does my answer not explain that clearly enough?  Would that example of two memcpy into the same buffer help?

Comment: @HCSF: That is not correct.  See my answer on this question.  Part of the point of `__builtin___clear_cache()` (and the only point on ISAs like x86) is that `sum()` does *not* get treated as having a dependency on the `memcpy(sum, ...)`.  This is like strict-aliasing where you can think of machine code as having a different type from any kind of data, and even `char*` alias-anything isn't sufficient to define the behaviour.

Comment: @AntoineMathys: That would be sufficient, yes.  If we're talking about mixing multiple `memcpy` and `sum()` calls, I'd do it after every `memcpy` instead of before each `sum()`, in case it had any deleterious effects on optimization of anything else.  (Like in case its memory-barrier effect applies generally).  I think you meant one clear_cache before *all* the subsequent `sum()` calls, not one before each, but "every" might imply the other meaning.

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant adding __builtin__clear_cache() before the first call to sum(), and after that, for each subsequent call to sum(), adding it before it if and only if the memory has been written to since the last call to sum().

Comment: AntoineMathys and @HCSF: I tried to reproduce the effect I was suggested with modifying the buffer again after the first call.  https://godbolt.org/z/nEpaQX.  But GCC has to assume that `sum()` reads or modifies arbitrary global memory *as data*, it can't optimize away the store between the first and second call.  GCC doesn't know about `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` so it has to assume that `mmap` return value might be a pointer to memory that's accessible via other methods.  That's also why order is respected for the first memcpy and call to `sum()`.

Comment: @AntoineMathys: I'd suggest rolling back to revision 10; I think the English text explaining that you need an executable page is at least as useful as this convoluted recipe using `mmap`.  Also, I agree that `__builtin___clear_cache()` is distracting clutter for people who really just to test shellcode, not actually write a JIT.  Especially when non-inline-function potential data dependence on writes to non-local memory in practice mean there's no problem unless you use `malloc` + `mprotect`.  Using `#ifdef __GNUC__` would make the clutter even worse, and would let it work on non-GNU with mmap

Comment: @HCSF: and Antoine: I was able to provoke GCC into breaking something by using `__attribute__((const))` to tell the optimizer it's a pure function (that only reads its args, not global memory).  Then dead-store elimination can happen on a memcpy before and after the call, resulting in no store before the first call = `00 00  add [rax], al` = segfault.  https://godbolt.org/z/6VNsav  (Godbolt's `./a.out` option to run the program still seems to fail, but it works on my desktop with __clear_cache and crashes without.)  However `attribute(const)` still CSEs calls over modifying the machine code.

Comment: I expanded the `__builtin___clear_cache` section in my answer with what I had added as a footnote to this answer.  I included a link for readers of this answer that wonder why removing `__clear_cache` doesn't actually break this code.

Comment: @PeterCordes This answer is now just the way I like it: simple and correct. If you have yet other suggestions, please leave a comment.

Comment: Looks good to me, and good improvement to the comments in the code to remove the word "necessary", which might be taken as implying it would break in practice.  I tried to sneak in a mention of less convoluted ways to do this (`gcc -z execstack`), but if you really don't want that then I don't insist.  A pointer to another answer for details on `__clear_cache` is more than fine, and what I should have done in the first place instead of inlining a big footnote.

Answer (score 12):

Until recent Linux kernel versions (sometime before 5.4), you could simply compile with `gcc -z execstack` - that would make *all* pages executable, including read-only data (`.rodata`), and read-write data (`.data`) where `char code[] = "..."` goes.

**Now `-z execstack` only applies to the actual stack, so it currently works only for non-const local arrays.**  i.e. move `char code[] = ...` into `main`.  Modern systems make as few pages executable as possible as hardening against exploits.

---

See [Linux default behavior against `.data` section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64833715) for the kernel change, and [Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58260465) for the old behaviour: enabling Linux's `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` process for that program.  (In Linux 5.4, that Q&A shows you'd only get `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` for a missing `PT_GNU_STACK`, like a really old binary; modern GCC `-z execstack` would set `PT_GNU_STACK = RWX` metadata in the executable, which Linux 5.4 would handle as making only the stack itself executable.  At some point before that, `PT_GNU_STACK = RWX` did result in `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC`.)

The other option is to make system calls at runtime to copy into an executable page, or change permissions on the page it's in.  That's still more complicated than using a local array to get GCC to copy code into executable stack memory.

(I don't know if there's an easy way to enable `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` under modern kernels.  Having no GNU-stack attribute at all in an ELF binary does that for 32-bit code, but not 64-bit.)

Yet another option is `__attribute__((section(".text"))) const char code[] = ...;`
Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/draGeh.
If you need the array to be writeable, e.g. for shellcode that inserts some zeros into strings, you could maybe link with `ld -N`.  But probably best to use -z execstack and a local array.

---

Two problems in the question:

- **exec permission on the page,** because you used an array that will go in the noexec read+write `.data` section.
- **your machine code doesn't end with a `ret` instruction** so even if it did run, execution would fall into whatever was next in memory instead of returning.

And BTW, the REX prefix is redundant.  `"\x31\xc0"` `xor eax,eax` [has exactly the same effect as `xor rax,rax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).

---

**You need the page containing the machine code to have execute permission**.  x86-64 page tables have a separate bit for execute separate from read permission, unlike legacy 386 page tables.

The easiest way to get static arrays to be in read+exec memory was to compile with **`gcc -z execstack`**.  (Used to make the stack *and* other sections executable, now only the stack).

```
typedef int (*intfunc_int)(int);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char execbuf[] = {   // compile with -zexecstack
        0x8d, 0x47, 0x01,     // lea 0x1(%rdi),%eax
        0xc3                  // ret
    };
    // a string initializer like  char execbuf[] = "\xc3"; also works

    // Tell GCC we're about to run this data as code.  x86 has coherent I-cache,
    // but this also stops optimization from removing the initialization as dead stores.
    __builtin___clear_cache (execbuf, execbuf+sizeof(execbuf)-1);
    // Without this, the store disappears

    intfunc_int fptr = (intfunc_int) execbuf;  // cast to function pointer.
    int res = fptr(2);           // deref the function pointer
    
    return res;    // returns 3 on non-Windows ISAs where the first arg is in EDI
}
```

Compiles to simple asm ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBLSAA6oCoRODB7evnoJSY4CQSHhLFExUraY9jkMQgRMxARpPn5cpeUpVTUEeWGR0RIAzLbVtfUZTQqDHcFdhT1cvQCUtqhexMjsHAQAnnGYWFQA1MEEexAAVIdUXgzIAPqHcxB3Jr1WGgCCJm%2BHeyxMwRAAbqg8Og5h93gB2F6vPYwvaXJLAELoPbIBA1PaYVSYZARLxUEwAVisBIAInsnmSTJDYQB6Gko1AsOJ0TB7ADuhAQewAtAAvTHYsZMZAAazBsIlew0qgAHOhSFLVJJwQrpRompK6Xt6ExFVwIOYCcR8AtDZgmKpxZKYdLkL1rQ7NfTiJgCFaYVSSU8oe69lqACplWh7ADibjc7MwYA4Lr2TAiSyORD2xEuewICDwCj26CY1Tj2bQWAAdDDZQA2PZowuoBDRRhHACS3NEqMwpF9WtxScz2bEClQezGqDi2ZHjhYeF5eZSeyoxEZKcwLFQ/2CwHTdbjxGITA2BwYyTEU5nAgLOfNyOHLoUxbB5l6eCouz2ciE2GubgC2FeACVP68bgABLYJ29IAOqcomm5ZgqGasterL4AoTBxNsNQKL61zXLidCOAw2HXMgOrEERwpbhAAo4niCpUbi%2BKWEk/KoFQlFYtRVBzNyXCgs895mL0rhPvebwSuclw3F8VBxAQxDkr0ZIPIIFxXLcghzBi7H0d6vpfDe8lktJskQGYvFQhKvougQywMEumF8W8npghwCy0JwBK8H4HBaKQqCcG41jWEOSwrKyD48KQBCaC5CwiiAvQEsWvTggSZiSL0kgAJzlgSqW9GY%2BicJInnRb5nC8AoIAaJF0ULHAsAwIgKCMsy9BkBQEBoEyLIxMAswFTQtAENElUQBEpURMENQbJwEWTcwxAbAA8hE2jYlF3C8F1bCCEtDC0DN3m8FguLAG4Yi0JVm2kFgPxGOIR03XgLoOHg/yYFdPlUV4w2lYcZSlbQeARLui0eFgpWyXgLCzS5fAGMACgAGp4JgbJLdsXkRfwggiGI7AlDj8hKGopW6AVBhGCggWWPowOVZACzjikV3cqoyA8kt9rcuBF08iSb4fl%2BP7/m4gEgTy/LsUKoq8Ku0TEMCH3wAsdjrSkLgMO4ngNP4WudAURSZIkyQCMMjSkFkpsMAb3TFM06sCG0Qw6yMDuvU74y29M9tCi76QW37Ez5HbEiqyFqxh4VHAeaQXk%2BX5HB7BW3LlpIezAMgHOzMWZjHLghAkOSAk8bwG1aHMCx1kwWAxBAsXxWYufKmY4LluC4ICRo4LSG5HDFaQMMEtV8dy%2BVthVTVR11Y1EBIImcQ/eQlBda10ShKwawp2nGdZ3sOdmLwOyF4r6B6ETePiITsiKCo6iPeTpBsrucSw657klY9idLT9i9HCxycZTllTunTO2dei52OB4bqbVi75TmGXWqVdLw9HrtHAeQ8R6lUThVSe5cYqkDivlZunc24dy7j3aOvRP4J3Hvgme8B6pNVXj1ZenUWo9RAH1fKfA8IjUoONR681pqw1IMIxaK01oOFEdtBse0DqlROl4M6F0roRVuoYYAD0fL4Beo4d6n0j7sR%2BmsHy/0%2B4%2BSBiDaa4NTFl0VjDTaCwqAI2RqjdGmNREX1EFfaQRNb6kwfnoSmxgaY2CsQzNBzMBCs3ZpzbmvNaDBkllRGWIo5bvR3ErSJqsyiOz8JRLW5s9boG9kbJoVsKjFIqSbCoZSZjuwqM7OortA55I9pUL2kxDYNKDtUgY7R6nFHDssSOPFo6x1HmVJO29QF7wPvnfARA5LhQQVPCuDcsrFhlLMLgBJejZS4LMcsGg0roN4JguO2Dx6VWqvQ0gTC54gAXkvDqLC2obzYJwWZu8ObliSkfJZJBgTn1kJfAmfib4k3vj5XQTRn6oTfhMmhY8OA/wIH/PYACflgP3hAvOEBoFrxWSXNZ9DkE11Qe/fuFyQDDyuV/G5eCkGEMbklDuypMrgl6EcyQpzMpUJRdMxB09qWH0HhIDQWDGUcBFRs0gmSkjOEkEAA%3D%3D) - also showing that it's broken without the `__builtin___clear_cache` - it will skip the store and just jump to uninitialized stack space.)  This runs correctly with `-z execstack`, will segfault without it.

```
# GCC -O3 for x86-64
main:
    sub     rsp, 24              # GCC reserves 16 bytes more stack space than it needed
    mov     edi, 2               # function arg
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], -1023326323  # store 4 bytes of machine code
    lea     rax, [rsp+12]        # pointer into a register
    call    rax                  # call through the function pointer
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
```

---

#### Older GNU `ld` linker used to make `.rodata` read+exec

Until recently (2018 or 2019), the standard toolchain (binutils `ld`) would put section `.rodata` into the same ELF segment as `.text`, so they'd both have read+exec permission.  Thus using **`const char code[] = "...";`** was sufficient for executing manually-specified bytes as data, without execstack.

But on my Arch Linux system with `GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.31.1`, that's no longer the case.  `readelf -a` shows that the `.rodata` section went into an ELF segment with `.eh_frame_hdr` and `.eh_frame`, and it only has Read permission.  `.text` goes in a segment with Read + Exec, and `.data` goes in a segment with Read + Write (along with the `.got` and `.got.plt`).  ([What's the difference of section and segment in ELF file format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14361248))

I assume this change is to make ROP and Spectre attacks harder by not having read-only data in executable pages where sequences of useful bytes could be used as "gadgets" that end with the bytes for a `ret` or `jmp reg` instruction.

```
// See above for char code[] = {...} inside main with -z execstack, for current Linux

// This is broken on recent Linux, used to work without execstack.
#include <stdio.h>

// can be non-const if you use gcc -z execstack.  static is also optional
static const char code[] = {
  0x8D, 0x04, 0x37,           //  lea eax,[rdi+rsi]       // retval = a+b;                    
  0xC3                        //  ret                                         
};

static const char ret0_code[] = "\x31\xc0\xc3";   // xor eax,eax ;  ret
                     // the compiler will append a 0 byte to terminate the C string,
                     // but that's fine.  It's after the ret.

int main () {
  // void* cast is easier to type than a cast to function pointer,
  // and in C can be assigned to any other pointer type.  (not C++)

  int (*sum) (int, int) = (void*)code;
  int (*ret0)(void) = (void*)ret0_code;

  // run code                                                                   
  int c = sum (2, 3);
  return ret0();
}
```

On older Linux systems: `gcc -O3 shellcode.c && ./a.out` (Works because of `const` on global/static arrays)

**On Linux before 5.5 (or so) `gcc -O3 -z execstack shellcode.c && ./a.out`** (works because of `-zexecstack` regardless of where your machine code is stored).  Fun fact: gcc allows `-zexecstack` with no space, but clang only accepts `clang -z execstack`.

These also work on Windows, where read-only data goes in `.rdata` instead of `.rodata`.

The compiler-generated `main` looks like this (from `objdump -drwC -Mintel`).  **You can run it inside `gdb` and set breakpoints on `code` and `ret0_code`**

```
(I actually used   gcc -no-pie -O3 -zexecstack shellcode.c  hence the addresses near 401000
0000000000401020 <main>:
  401020:       48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8           # stack aligned by 16 before a call
  401024:       be 03 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x3
  401029:       bf 02 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x2           # 2 args
  40102e:       e8 d5 0f 00 00          call   402008 <code>     # note the target address in the next page; that's where .rodata goes
  401033:       48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  401037:       e9 c8 0f 00 00          jmp    402004 <ret0_code>    # optimized tailcall
```

---

#### Or use system calls to modify page permissions

Instead of compiling with `gcc -zexecstack`, you can instead use `mmap(PROT_EXEC)` to allocate new executable pages, or `mprotect(PROT_EXEC)` to change existing pages to executable.  (Including pages holding static data.)  You also typically want at least `PROT_READ` and sometimes `PROT_WRITE`, of course.

Using `mprotect` on a static array means you're still executing the code from a known location, maybe making it easier to set a breakpoint on it.

On Windows you can use VirtualAlloc or VirtualProtect.

---

### Telling the compiler that data is executed as code

Normally compilers like GCC assume that data and code are separate.  This is like type-based strict aliasing, but even using `char*` doesn't make it well-defined to store into a buffer and then call that buffer as a function pointer.

**In GNU C, you also need to use [`__builtin___clear_cache(buf, buf + len)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) after writing machine code bytes to a buffer**, because the optimizer doesn't treat dereferencing a function pointer as reading bytes from that address.  Dead-store elimination can remove the stores of machine code bytes into a buffer, if the compiler proves that  the store isn't read as data by anything.  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/the-repetitive-byte-counter/160236#160236 and https://godbolt.org/g/pGXn3B has an example where gcc really does do this optimization, because gcc "knows about" `malloc`.  Also the first code block in this answer, where we use a local array in executable stack space.

(And on non-x86 architectures where I-cache isn't coherent with D-cache, it actually will do any necessary cache syncing.  On x86 it's purely a compile-time optimization blocker and doesn't expand to any instructions itself, because a jump or call is sufficient on paper for JIT or self-modifying code, and [in practice it's completely impossible to observe stale code after a store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395557/observing-stale-instruction-fetching-on-x86-with-self-modifying-code) on real x86 CPUs.)

Re: the weird name with three underscores: It's the usual `__builtin_name` pattern, but `name` is `__clear_cache`.

My edit on @AntoineMathys's answer added this.

In practice GCC/clang don't "know about" `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` the way they know about `malloc`.  So in practice the optimizer will assume that the memcpy into the buffer might be read as data by the non-inline function call through the function pointer, even without `__builtin___clear_cache()`.  (Unless you declared the function type as `__attribute__((const))`.)

On x86, where I-cache is coherent with data caches, having the stores happen in asm before the call is sufficient for correctness.  On other ISAs, `__builtin___clear_cache()` will actually emit special instructions as well as ensuring the right compile-time ordering.

It's good practice to include it when copying code into a buffer because it doesn't cost performance, and stops hypothetical future compilers from breaking your code.  (e.g. if they do understand that `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` gives newly-allocated anonymous memory that nothing else has a pointer to, just like malloc.)

---

**With current GCC, I was able to provoke GCC into really doing an optimization we don't want by using `__attribute__((const))`** to tell the optimizer `sum()` is a pure function (that only reads its args, not global memory).  GCC then knows `sum()` can't read the result of the `memcpy` as data.

With another `memcpy` into the same buffer after the call, GCC does dead-store elimination into just the 2nd store *after* the call.  This results in no store before the first call so it executes the `00 00  add [rax], al` bytes, segfaulting.

```
// demo of a problem on x86 when not using __builtin___clear_cache
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main ()
{
  char code[] = {
    0x8D, 0x04, 0x37,           //  lea eax,[rdi+rsi]
    0xC3                        //  ret                                         
  };

  __attribute__((const)) int (*sum) (int, int) = NULL;

  // copy code to executable buffer                                             
  sum = mmap (0,sizeof(code),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
              MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0);
  memcpy (sum, code, sizeof(code));
  //__builtin___clear_cache(sum, sum + sizeof(code));

  int c = sum (2, 3);
  //printf ("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);

  memcpy(sum, (char[]){0x31, 0xc0, 0xc3, 0}, 4);  // xor-zero eax, ret, padding for a dword store
  //__builtin___clear_cache(sum, sum + 4);
  return sum(2,3);
}
```

Compiled [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Csys/mman.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main+()%0A%7B%0A++char+code%5B%5D+%3D+%7B%0A++++0x8D,+0x04,+0x37,+++++++++++//++lea+eax,%5Brdi%2Brsi%5D%0A++++0xC3++++++++++++++++++++++++//++ret+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%0A++%7D%3B%0A%0A++//+modifying+the+code+of+an+attribute((const))+function+breaks+the+optimizer:%0A++//+gcc+still+CSEs+2+calls+through+the+same+pointer+even+with+memcpy+%2B+__clear_cache%0A++//+so+don!%27t+do+that.++const+means+the+function+only+depends+on+its+args,+not+global+state%0A++__attribute__((const))+int+(*sum)+(int,+int)+%3D+NULL%3B%0A%0A++//+copy+code+to+executable+buffer+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%0A++sum+%3D+mmap+(0,sizeof(code),PROT_READ%7CPROT_WRITE%7CPROT_EXEC,%0A++++++++++++++MAP_PRIVATE%7CMAP_ANON,-1,0)%3B%0A++memcpy+(sum,+code,+sizeof(code))%3B%0A%0A%23ifdef+__GNUC__%0A++//__builtin___clear_cache(sum,+sum+%2B+sizeof(code))%3B%0A%23endif%0A%0A++//+run+code+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%0A++int+a+%3D+2%3B%0A++int+b+%3D+3%3B%0A++int+c+%3D+sum+(a,+b)%3B%0A++//printf+(%22%25d+%2B+%25d+%3D+%25d%5Cn%22,+a,+b,+c)%3B%0A%0A++memcpy(sum,+(char%5B%5D)%7B0x31,+0xc0,+0xc3,+0%7D,+4)%3B++//+xor-zero+eax,+ret,+padding+for+a+dword+store%0A++//__builtin___clear_cache(sum,+sum+%2B+4)%3B%0A++return+sum(2,3)%3B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23if+0%0A//+__clear_cache+seems+to+be+a+general+memory+barrier:+even+syncs+the+stack+buffer%0A//+if+you+put+this+before+return%0A++code%5B0%5D+%3D+0xC3%3B+//+ret%0A++__builtin___clear_cache(code,+code+%2B+1)%3B%0A%23endif%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with GCC9.2 -O3

```
main:
        push    rbx
        xor     r9d, r9d
        mov     r8d, -1
        mov     ecx, 34
        mov     edx, 7
        mov     esi, 4
        xor     edi, edi
        sub     rsp, 16
        call    mmap
        mov     esi, 3
        mov     edi, 2
        mov     rbx, rax
        call    rax                  # call before store
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], 12828721    #  0xC3C031 = xor-zero eax, ret
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        ret                      # no 2nd call, CSEd away because const and same args
```

Passing different args would have gotten another `call reg`, but **even with `__builtin___clear_cache` the two `sum(2,3)` calls can CSE**.  `__attribute__((const))` doesn't respect changes to the machine code of a function.  Don't do it.  It's safe if you're going to JIT the function once and then call many times, though.

Uncommenting the first `__clear_cache` results in

```
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], -1019804531    # lea; ret
        call    rax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], 12828721       # xor-zero; ret
       ... still CSE and use the RAX return value
```

The first store is there because of `__clear_cache` and the `sum(2,3)` call.  (Removing the first `sum(2,3)` call does let dead-store elimination happen across the `__clear_cache`.)

The second store is there because the side-effect on the buffer returned by `mmap` is assumed to be important, and that's the final value `main` leaves.

Godbolt's `./a.out` option to run the program still seems to always fail (exit status of 255); maybe it sandboxes JITing?  It works on my desktop with `__clear_cache` and crashes without.

---

### `mprotect` on a page holding existing C variables.

You can also give a single existing page read+write+exec permission.  This is an alternative to compiling with `-z execstack`

You don't need `__clear_cache` on a page holding read-only C variables because there's no store to optimize away.  You would still need it for initializing a local buffer (on the stack).  Otherwise GCC will optimize away the initializer for this private buffer that a non-inline function call definitely doesn't have a pointer to.  (Escape analysis).  It doesn't consider the possibility that the buffer might hold the machine code for the function unless you tell it that via `__builtin___clear_cache`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// can be non-const if you want, we're using mprotect
static const char code[] = {
  0x8D, 0x04, 0x37,           //  lea eax,[rdi+rsi]       // retval = a+b;                    
  0xC3                        //  ret                                         
};

static const char ret0_code[] = "\x31\xc0\xc3";

int main () {
  // void* cast is easier to type than a cast to function pointer,
  // and in C can be assigned to any other pointer type.  (not C++)
  int (*sum) (int, int) = (void*)code;
  int (*ret0)(void) = (void*)ret0_code;

   // hard-coding x86's 4k page size for simplicity.
   // also assume that `code` doesn't span a page boundary and that ret0_code is in the same page.
  uintptr_t page = (uintptr_t)code & -4095ULL;                  // round down
  mprotect((void*)page, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE);  // +write in case the page holds any writeable C vars that would crash later code.

  // run code                                                                   
  int c = sum (2, 3);
  return ret0();
}
```

I used `PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE` in this example so it works regardless of where your variable is.  If it was a local on the stack and you left out `PROT_WRITE`, `call` would fail after making the stack read only when it tried to push a return address.

**Also, `PROT_WRITE` lets you test shellcode that self-modifies, e.g. to edit zeros into its own machine code, or other bytes it was avoiding.**

```
$ gcc -O3 shellcode.c           # without -z execstack
$ ./a.out 
$ echo $?
0
$ strace ./a.out
...
mprotect(0x55605aa3f000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

If I comment out the `mprotect`, it *does* segfault with recent versions of GNU Binutils `ld` which no longer put read-only constant data into the same ELF segment as the `.text` section.

If I did something like `ret0_code[4] = 0xc3;`, I would need `__builtin___clear_cache(ret0_code+2, ret0_code+2)` after that to make sure the store wasn't optimized away, but if I don't modify the static arrays then it's not needed after `mprotect`.  It is needed after `mmap`+`memcpy` or manual stores, because we want to execute bytes that have been written in C (with `memcpy`).

Comment: @AntoineMathys: The other reason is to test out a snippet of shellcode to make sure you've correctly turned an assembly program into part of an exploit payload.  If you were JITing, you wouldn't have a C string like the OP's `"\x48\x31\xc0"`, you'd just have bytes.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the assembly in-line via a special compiler directive so that it'll properly end up in a code segment.  See this guide, for example: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 6):

Your machine code may be all right, but your CPU objects.

Modern CPUs manage memory in segments.  In normal operation, the operating system loads a new program into a *program-text* segment and sets up a stack in a *data* segment.  The operating system tells the CPU never to run code in a data segment.  Your code is in `code[]`, in a data segment.  Thus the segfault.

Answer (score 3):

This will take some effort.

Your `code` variable is stored in the `.data` section of your executable:

```
$ readelf -p .data exploit

String dump of section '.data':
  [    10]  H1À
```

`H1À` is the value of your variable.

The `.data` section is *not* executable:

```
$ readelf -S exploit
There are 30 section headers, starting at offset 0x1150:
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
[...]
  [24] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000601010  00001010
       0000000000000014  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
```

All 64-bit processors I'm familiar with support non-executable pages natively in the pagetables. Most newer 32-bit processors (the ones that support PAE) provide enough extra space in their pagetables for the operating system to emulate hardware non-executable pages. You'll need to run either an ancient OS or an ancient processor to get a `.data` section marked executable.

Because these are just flags in the executable, you ought to be able to set the `X` flag through some other mechanism, but I don't know how to do so. And your OS might not even let you have pages that are both writable *and* executable.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the page executable before you may call it.
On MS-Windows, see the VirtualProtect -function.

URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I couldn't follow above examples which are complicated.
So, I created an elegant solution for executing hex code from C.
Basically, you could use asm and .word keywords to place your instructions in hex format.
See below example:

```
asm volatile(".rept 1024\n"
             CNOP
           ".endr\n");
```

where CNOP is defined as below:
#define ".word 0x00010001 \n"

Basically, `c.nop` instruction was not supported by my current assembler. So, I defined `CNOP` as the hex equivalent of `c.nop` with proper syntax and used inside asm, with which I was aware of.
`.rept <NUM> .endr` will basically, repeat the instruction NUM times.

This solution is working and verified.

Comment: Normally when people want to test shellcode, they have a string like `"\x31\xc0\xc3"`, not broken up into `.byte 0x??, 0x??, ...` or `.word` chunks.  But yes, if you do that, that's another way to turn it into  machine code in an executable page.  (In the middle of a function, so most instructions other than NOP will need clobber declarations to tell the compiler what it does to registers, unless it exits or does execve so execution doesn't leave the asm statement).