# Exactly what cases does the gcc execstack flag allow and how does it enforce it?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, shellcode

I have some example code here which I'm using to understand some C behaviour for a beginner's CTF:

```
// example.c

#include <stdio.h>


void main() {
        void (*print)();

        print = getenv("EGG");
        print();
}
```

Compile: `gcc -z execstack -g -m32 -o example example.c`

Usage: `EGG=$(echo -ne '\x90\xc3) ./example`

If I compile the code with the `execstack` flag, the program will execute the opcodes I've injected above. Without the flag, the program will crash due to a segmentation fault.

Why exactly is this? Is it because `getenv` is storing the actual opcodes on the stack, and the execstack flag allows jumps to the stack? Or does `getenv` push a pointer onto the stack, and there are some other rules about what sections of memory are executable? I read the manpage, but I couldn't work out exactly what the rules are and how they're enforced.

Another issue is I think I'm also really lacking a good tool to visualise memory whilst debugging, so its hard to figure this out. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: *I'm also really lacking a good tool to visualise memory* -- you can use a combination of `gdb` and `/proc/<pid>/maps` (to check permissions etc on the sections)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`getenv` doesn't *store* the env var's value on the stack.  It's *already* on the stack from process startup, and `getenv` obtains a pointer to it.**

See the i386 System V ABI's description of where argv[] and envp[] are located at process startup: above `[esp]`.

`_start` doesn't copy them before calling `main`, just calculates pointers to them to pass as args to `main`.  (Links to the latest version at https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI, where the official current version is maintained.)

---

Your code is casting a pointer to stack memory (containing the value of an env var) into a function pointer and calling through it.  Look at the compiler-generated asm (e.g. on https://godbolt.org/): it'll be something like `call getenv` / `call eax`.

**`-zexecstack` in your kernel version<sup>1</sup> makes all your pages executable, not just the stack**.  It also applies to `.data`, `.bss`, and `.rodata` sections, and memory allocated with `malloc` / `new`.

**The exact mechanism on GNU/Linux was a "read-implies-exec" process-wide flag that affects all future allocations, including manual use of `mmap`.**  See [Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260465/unexpected-exec-permission-from-mmap-when-assembly-files-included-in-the-project) for more about the `GNU_STACK` ELF header stuff.

**Footnote 1**: Linux after 5.4 or so only makes the stack itself executable, not READ_IMPLIES_EXEC: [Linux default behavior of executable .data section changed between 5.4 and 5.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833715/linux-default-behavior-against-data-section/64837581#64837581)

Fun fact: taking the address of a nested function that accesses its parents local variables gets gcc to enable `-zexecstack`.  It stores code for an executable "trampoline" onto the stack that passes a "static chain" pointer to the actual nested function, allowing it to reference its parent's stack-frame.

---

If you wanted to exec data as code without `-zexecstack`, you'd use `mprotect(PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE)` on the page containing that env var.  (It's part of your stack so you shouldn't remove write permission; it could be in the same page as main's stack frame for example.)

---

Related:

With GNU/Linux `ld` from binutils before late 2018 or so, the `.rodata` section is linked into the same ELF segment as the `.text` section, and thus `const char code[] = {0xc3}` or string literals are executable.

Current `ld` gives `.rodata` its own segment that's mapped read without exec, so finding ROP / Spectre "gadgets" in read-only data is no longer possible, unless you use `-zexecstack`.  And even that doesn't work on current kernels; `char code[] = ...;` as a local inside a function will put data on the stack where it's actually executable.  See [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960721/how-to-get-c-code-to-execute-hex-machine-code/55893781#55893781) for details.

Comment: Nice answer.  So if I copy the content of what `getenv()` returns into an executable `mmap`-ed region, then `-zexecstack` isn't needed?  Because that `mmap`-ed region isn't on the stack?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any downside of using `-zexecstack`?  Such as performance?  If not, I would imagine gcc makes it a default?

Comment: @HCSF: Yes, you can copy data into a page with `PROT_EXEC` permission, or more simply use `mprotect` to change permissions on the existing page.  The obvious massive downsize to `-zexecstack` is security: any buffer-overflow vulnerability of a stack buffer allows a code-injection exploit directly without having to find ROP gadgets to "return" to.  There's no performance downside.  GCC actually does enable if if you take the address of a nested function.

Comment: @HCSF: see [How to get c code to execute hex bytecode?](//stackoverflow.com/a/55893781) for more about executing data as code with GCC.