# Buffer overflow, pointing to the proper address but still not working

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow, exploit

So I am trying to implement a buffer overflow to get shell access to a buggy machine.

The machine is

- freebsd
- little endian byte reading
- String length is 200 which causes the overflow.

Now after consulting http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-106.php to get a shellcode for /bin/sh and modifying the string, this is what I made

NO-Ops: "\x90"x164

SHELLCODE: "\x48\x31\xc0\x99\xb0\x3b\x48\xbf\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xef\x08x57\x48\x89\xe7\x57\x52\x48\x89\xe6\x0f\x05";print

Address to jump to :"\x68\xea\xff\xff\xff\x7f";' # 0x7fffffffea68 is in the middle of the No-Ops.

The problem is, I can get my EIP to point to 0x7fffffffea68 exactly. However when the segmentation fault occurs, the address shows up as 0x00007fffffffae68. How do I navigate to the address 0x7fffffffea68 as it shows up without the 4 zeros when I look at the registers from the stack pointer ? The address is correct but can not jump there as it is "incorrect".

This is how the address shows up during segmentation fault. (ignore ea/ae here, the problem is same both ways)
[image: How it appears on segmentation fault]

Here is the output of `info registers`.
[image: The instruction pointer to address]

Here is how it appears on the dump (to show the intended address).
[image: w.r.t stack pointers, giving the address to jump into]

I do not understand where I am going wrong with this. The likely answer is the address to jump to so I tried making various changes to the lengths and where to jump to. It still does not work.

The second could be the shellcode but I put my money on the length. I need help to understand where I might be wrong and how I can go about mitigating this problem. Thanks.

Comment: 0x7fffffffae68 and 0x00007fffffffae68 are the very same numbers. It is quite common to suppress leading zeroes.

Comment: The memory dump is at 0x7fffffffea68, not 0x7fffffffae68.

Comment: Sorry, added the correction between ae and ea. ea is the correct one. the problem is same regardless.

Comment: "Invalid permission" could mean that you are not allowed to execute code from the data segment. A common virus protection feature.

Comment: ohh. Makes sense. Let me try this with root.

Comment: Did not work that way as well but let me try looking from the suggested problem. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: There's a backslash missing in `"\x48\x31\xc0\x99\xb0\x3b\x48\xbf\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xef\x08x57\x48\x89\xe7\x57\x52\x48\x89\xe6\x0f\x05";print`. This is not going to fly.

Comment: Processes running as `root` don't have all their pages read+write+exec, that would be the absolute last thing you'd want, making them more vulnerable to code-injection attacks like this!!  You probably need to build with `gcc -z execstack` to make the stack itself executable (previously that made all pages executable, but not anymore).  See [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960721) for example, and [Exactly what cases does the gcc execstack flag allow and how does it enforce it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53346274)

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes. Will try this path.