# difference between .text and .data

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I want to know what is the difference between the data section and text section in terms of the entire code in a specific section.

I was trying to run the code I have added here. 
In the data sectoin it runs and prints "af)a"
If I change it to the text section in line 2, it seg fault.

I can't figure out what are the crucial differences.
Thanks :)

```
global _start
section .data

_start: mov ecx, 3
    xor byte [_start + 1], 0x02
    pushad  
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, ecx
    mov ecx, dword blah
    int 0x80
blah:   popad
    sub bx, ax
    loop _start
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 2
    int 0x80
fin:
```

expected code to yield the same result, but was proven otherwise.

Comment: The text section is executable but not writable, the data section is writable but not executable.  Some operating system cannot enforce the “no execute” rule.

Comment: `.text` is typically read only, executable. `.data` is read-write and is not supposed to be executable although sometimes (as in your case) it is. Note those are just built-in default attributes. See also [7.9.2 elf Extensions to the SECTION Directive](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.2) in the nasm manual.

Comment: Your code seems very overcomplicated.  You use the slow `loop` instruction, but you reset the loop counter to `3` inside the loop.  And you save/restore all the registers with `pushad`/`popad` for no reason.  Just use `jmp _start` instead of `loop`.  Or if you want a non-infinite loop, use a different register for the counter.

Comment: If only I had a say.. this is my professor weird mind haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> difference between `.text` and `.data`

I don't know about the MASM assembler but the GNU assembler makes two differences:

1. The name (`.text` in one case, `.data` in the other case). However, this name is *ignored* by the operating system.
2. The section flags in the executable file:

   - `SHF_ALLOC | SHF_EXECINSTR` for `.text` and
   - `SHF_ALLOC | SHF_WRITE` for `.data`

The "section flags" tell the operating system what kind of data is present in the section and what kind of operations are allowed:

- `SHF_EXECINSTR` means that the section contains code which can be executed. If this flag misses, the program will crash in most OSs if the section contains code. Older 32-bit CPUs did not support this, so this flag was ignored by many OSs when running 32-bit programs. Obviously, your OS ignores this flag; otherwise the `.data` variant of your program would crash because the code is located in the `.data` section.
- `SHF_WRITE` means that data in the section can be overwritten. If this flag is missing and you are trying to do a write operation to the data in the section, the program will crash.

Of course it would be possible to manipulate the executable file in a way that the section `.text` has the `SHF_WRITE` flag set. (And some assemblers allow setting this flag for the `.text` section directly.) In this case your program would not crash if you write to the `.text` section.

Comment: You can get executable `.data` (and stack and BSS) by linking with `gcc -zexecstack`.   The `ld` man page documents `ld -N` (aka `ld --omagic`) to give the text segment read+write permission.  (And the `.text` section gets linked into the text segment of an executable).

Comment: Update to previous comment: on modern Linux kernels, the ELF flag set by `gcc -z execstack` truly only makes the stack itself executable.  See  [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55893781)