# Why CLFLUSH affects nothing?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, cpu-cache

The following code reads an array in that way that it loads one element per cache line, supposing that it is **64 bytes**, then makes use of `clflush` for each line and reads the array once again. That said, timings of the second reading are shorter. I wonder why. It seems that clflush does not invalidate the cache lines.

Btw, Do the cache lines consist of exactly **64 bytes** per line?
I have this question since I have tried to change the step from **16** `int`s to **32** and even **64**, but the second reading has been still faster.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#define ARR1_LEN 16384

#define PRINT_DUR {\
    printf("%ld - %ld = %ld\n%.20Lf\n", t2, t1, t2-t1, ((long double)(t2 - t1))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);\
}

#define CLEAR_CACHE {\
    asm("movq %1, %%rcx; movq %0, %%rax; label_%=: clflush (%%rax); addq $64, %%rax; loop label_%= ;"::"r"(arr1), "i"((ARR1_LEN>>5) -1):"rcx", "rax");\
}


int main() {
    int *arr1_ = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR1_LEN + 64);
    int temp;
    if (!arr1_) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int *arr1 = (int*)((((size_t)arr1_)+63)&0xffffffffffffffc0);

    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < (ARR1_LEN>>4); i++) {
        temp = arr1[i<<4];
    }
    t2 = clock();

//  __builtin___clear_cache(arr1, arr1 + ARR1_LEN -1); // It compiles into nothing at all
    CLEAR_CACHE

    PRINT_DUR

    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < (ARR1_LEN>>4); i++) {
        temp = arr1[(i<<4) + 32];
    }
    t2 = clock();

    PRINT_DUR

    free(arr1_);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, `__builtin___clear_cache` is misnamed.  The actual meaning is "sync I-cache", making it safe to execute data (you just stored) as code.  x86 has coherent I-caches, so the only effect is to tell the optimizer the store-data is used, not dead.  [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55893781) links an example where it's necessary.  It's irrelevant to what you're doing, though.

Comment: The first read costs page faults or at least TLB misses on top of cache misses.  My answer on [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) includes links to some details about that.  If you touch one line per page first, or allocate with `mmap(MAP_POPULATE)`, it'll be difference.  And yes, lines are 64 bytes on all modern x86 CPUs.

Comment: Also, you concluded that clflush doesn't invalidate anything.  To conclude that, you'd have to count cache misses with perf counters, and see that you got the same number with/without clflush.  Not just that the 2nd time was faster - you haven't ruled out other reasons.  Microbenchmarking is hard!

Comment: Oh BTW, your inline asm statement is very unsafe: you modify RCX without a clobber, and you modify `%0` even though you asked for it as a read-only input.  Use `_mm_clflush` from immintrin.h (and check the generated asm if you want to be sure).  Also, don't use the `loop` instruction, it's slow on Intel.