# Shellcode doesn't work whatsoever. Could it be a hardware/software problem?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, nasm, shellcode, penetration-testing

I'm trying to learn how to create shellcode. I've followed several tutorials online and I still can't get it to work. I start by writing clean assembly x86 code to spawn a shell, extract the opcode, and place it into a C file.

This is the assembly code:

```
;nasm -f elf64 test.nasm; ld test.o -o test  
section .text
global _start
_start:
    xor rax, rax
    push rax
    mov rax, 0x68732f6e69622f2f
    push rax
    mov rdi, rsp
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor rdx, rdx
    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 0x3b    ; execve()
    syscall
```

The objdump of the object file:

```
$ objdump -D -M intel test.o      

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
   3:   50                      push   rax
   4:   48 b8 2f 2f 62 69 6e    movabs rax,0x68732f6e69622f2f
   b:   2f 73 68 
   e:   50                      push   rax
   f:   48 89 e7                mov    rdi,rsp
  12:   48 31 f6                xor    rsi,rsi
  15:   48 31 d2                xor    rdx,rdx
  18:   48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
  1b:   b0 3b                   mov    al,0x3b
  1d:   0f 05                   syscall
```

And the C file with extracted opcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char code[] =
"\x48\x31\xc0\x50\x48\xb8\x2f\x2f"
"\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x50\x48"
"\x89\xe7\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2"
"\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x0f\x0";

void main() {
    printf(" shell length: %d\n", (int)strlen(code));
    int (*ret) () = (int(*) ()) code;
    ret();
}
//gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack test.c -o test2
```

After compiling and executing, I get a segmentation fault:

```
./test2                                     
 shell length: 30
zsh: segmentation fault  ./test2
```

How do I get this to work? Every tutorial implies the shellcode just works at this point. Now I'm wondering if it's a hardware/software issue. I'm running this on a Kali VM on VirtualBox:

[image]

NASM version is 2.16.01. GCC version is 12.2.0.

Comment: You are missing a 5 on the end of this line `"\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x0f\x0";` . It should be `"\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";` . Since you are using a Kernel >= 5.4 the data and rodata sections will not be given executable privileges so you will have to move  `code` array inside the function `main`  so that is gets run on the stack which will be executable.

Comment: [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960721)